# How to make calculated memberr display 0 when value is null by using format string in SSAS

Tags: ssas

How to make calculated memberr display 0 when value is null by using format string  in SSAS instead of using mdx query

Comment: "#,##0.00 %;-#,##0.00 %" , I tried this , but it is not working for me

Comment: @Yahya, I tried "#,##0.00 %;-#,##0.00 %" , I tried this , but it is not working for me

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you can try this.

```
WITH MEMBER [Measures].[New Measure]
AS
iif(ISEMPTY([Measures].[Old Measure]), 0,[Measures].[Old Measure])
```